# Xcode 15 - failed to emit precompiled header in flutter project

Tags: flutter, xcode

I'm trying to update the app on the AppStore, until I added the certificate for notifications it compiled without problems.
Since I added them I get this error:

> Failed to build iOS app Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not
> found
> /Users/leonardo/App/Flutter/fisioterapp%20apple/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8
>
> Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header
> '/Users/mauriziomancini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-awurfoldgajbfggyzvxrrzhhexef/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_10C06NYVOSSNQ-clang_2E8H12ULDRK22.pch'
> for bridging header '/Users/leonardo/App/Flutter/fisioterapp
> apple/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'

Encountered error while building for device.

I also tried:

1. rm Podfile.lock
2. rm pods folder
3. flutter clean
4. pod install
5. flutter build ios

but it did not work

this is my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end

target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

some help please.